# Connect different port width

Tags: system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

Suppose my module has a 8-bit input and 8-bit output

```
module MyModule (input logic [7:0] in, output logic [7:0] out);
    ...
endmodule : MyModule
```

If I want to connect a 1-bit input in and leave the other bits as zero, the following works:

```
MyModule (.in({7'b0, a}), .out(b))
```

How can I do the same if I want a 1-bit output, ignoring the other bits? Something like this

```
MyModule (.in(a), .out({7'b0, b}))
```

vcs says its invalid, and connecting `b` directly gives a warning. I'd ideally like a solution that doesn't throw warnings.

Here's what I've thought of:

- Use `.out(b)` and use `b[0]` for bit
- Create unused logic variable `unused` and use `.out({unused, b})` which does work
- Use `assign` statment (I'd like to avoid this)

Any solution better than these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the streaming operator:

```
MyModule M (.in(a), .out({<<{b}}));
```

But I think your first idea is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use parameterized modules:

```
module MyModule #(IN_WDT = 8, OUT_WDT = 8)
  (input logic[IN_WDT-1:0] in, output logic [OUT_WDT -1 : 0] out);

...

MyModule #(8,1) M1(a8, b1);
```

or

```
MyModule #(.OUT_WDT(1)) M1(.in(a8), .out(b1));
```

Comment: Won't this interfere with the internal logic of my module if I set output to be only 1 bit wide?

Comment: you have to code your module in a way which uses the parameters to declare and use correct widths through its logic.